# How can i mock the EventHubConsumerClient callback args with Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, azure-eventhub

I am creating an event hub consumer using the example code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-node-get-started-send

How should I mock the events and context which are passed a arguments to the callback?

```
const { EventHubConsumerClient, earliestEventPosition  } = require("@azure/event-hubs");
const { ContainerClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");    
const { BlobCheckpointStore } = require("@azure/eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob");

const connectionString = "EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE CONNECTION STRING";    
const eventHubName = "EVENT HUB NAME";
const consumerGroup = "$Default"; // name of the default consumer group
const storageConnectionString = "AZURE STORAGE CONNECTION STRING";
const containerName = "BLOB CONTAINER NAME";

async function main() {
  // Create a blob container client and a blob checkpoint store using the client.
  const containerClient = new ContainerClient(storageConnectionString, containerName);
  const checkpointStore = new BlobCheckpointStore(containerClient);

  // Create a consumer client for the event hub by specifying the checkpoint store.
  const consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(consumerGroup, connectionString, eventHubName, checkpointStore);

  // Subscribe to the events, and specify handlers for processing the events and errors.
  const subscription = consumerClient.subscribe({
      processEvents: async (events, context) => {
        if (events.length === 0) {
          console.log(`No events received within wait time. Waiting for next interval`);
          return;
        }

        for (const event of events) {
          console.log(`Received event: '${event.body}' from partition: '${context.partitionId}' and consumer group: '${context.consumerGroup}'`);
        }
        // Update the checkpoint.
        await context.updateCheckpoint(events[events.length - 1]);
      },

      processError: async (err, context) => {
        console.log(`Error : ${err}`);
      }
    },
    { startPosition: earliestEventPosition }
  );

  // After 30 seconds, stop processing.
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      await subscription.close();
      await consumerClient.close();
      resolve();
    }, 30000);
  });
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log("Error occurred: ", err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to know about the types of these two? The `processEvents` [callback has the following signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/event-hubs/processeventshandler?view=azure-node-latest)

```
type ProcessEventsHandler = (
  events: ReceivedEventData[],
  context: PartitionContext
) => Promise<void>
```

Here's the ref doc for `ReceivedEventData`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/event-hubs/receivedeventdata?view=azure-node-latest

and ref doc for `PartitionContext`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/event-hubs/partitioncontext?view=azure-node-latest

Not too familar with `jest`.  Here's what I tried:

```
async function processEvents(events, context) {
  if (events.length === 0) {
    console.log(`No events received within wait time. Waiting for next interval`);
    return;
  }

  for (const event of events) {
    console.log(`Received event: '${event.body}' from partition: '${context.partitionId}' and consumer group: '${context.consumerGroup}'`);
  }
  // Update the checkpoint.
  await context.updateCheckpoint(events[events.length - 1]);
}

test('empty events', async () => {
  const context = {
    updateCheckpoint: jest.fn()
  };
  await processEvents([], context);
  expect(context.updateCheckpoint.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
});

test('non-empty events', async () => {
  const context = {
    updateCheckpoint: jest.fn()
  };
  await processEvents([{ body: "hello"}], context);
  console.dir(context.updateCheckpoint.mock);
  expect(context.updateCheckpoint.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not sure how I would stub the context or events passed to this callback?

Comment: These are the interfaces describing the shape of these arguments, but these are arguments that are passed to a callback I define and pass to the subscribe method so I am unsure how I can mock them so that I can test that the updateCheckpoint method is called in certain conditions without invoking the event hub implementation of that method.

Comment: Not familiar with jest. you just need to test your event handler?

    test('empty events', async () => {
      const context = {
        updateCheckpoint: jest.fn()
      };
      await processEvents([], context);
      expect(context.updateCheckpoint.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
    });
    test('non-empty events', async () => {
      const context = {
        updateCheckpoint: jest.fn()
      };
      await processEvents([{ body: "hello"}], context);
      console.dir(context.updateCheckpoint.mock);
      expect(context.updateCheckpoint.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
    });

Comment: Edited my previous reply above.